# safari blocks event.source.postMessage

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari, postmessage

Safari 9.03

I am post messaging to an iframe and then responding on the message event with

```
event.source.postMessage({foo:'bar'}, event.origin);
```

Safari blocks this with the message:

Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:9002" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:9003". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

This works fine in chrome and firefox.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you try it on https?

Comment: I'll give it a go. That will take some time to setup etc.

What's the reasoning here? Do you think that will work? Or just a prod for more information?

Comment: I think It'll work see here, why would it take long to check? just throw an s on there

Comment: Okay, I threw an s on the end.

Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:5000" from accessing a frame with origin "https://localhost:3000". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

https also still works in Chrome.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue. Did you try anything else? Any progress at all?

Answer (score 0):

your port is different. try to work on the same protocol, domain and **port**

Comment: Can you explain why this may be the solution ? Documentation ?